# Android Device manager : "transfer error: Permission denied"

Tags: android

I am trying to pull my applications databases files, I can see that I have all the permissions in the database file "-rwxrwxrwx", which I provided by chmod -r 777 /data/data/com.example.myapp, but I am not able to, I constantly get the above error when I try to pull it and moreover the device manager keeps crashing.

The error that I get:

> [2015-07-19 19:48:44 - ddms] transfer error: Permission denied
>
> [2015-07-19 19:48:44] Failed to pull selection: Permission denied

I am using Android Studio, my device has root access and I am on a mac.

This is what I am trying to pull:

[image]

Edit: When I run the following command I get this error `Package 'com.example.hackbot' has corrupt installation` :

```
run-as com.example.hackbot chmod /data/data/com.example.hackbot/databases/HackBotDB
```

Any help is valuable.

Cheers

Comment: I found out a way in which I can do it, but it looks very ugly and it time consuming but works. I downloaded ES File Explorer File Manager(Any explorer which can access root files will work) from the play store, searched for by db file from the app made a copy of the file and moved it to the sd card, then I was able to access it from the device manager. And then just moved it to the DB Browser for SQL Lite to see the DB.

Comment: I hope there is some other solution also, a less painful one. Please let me know if any. This almost consumed my entire day and I still don't have a neat solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adb shell linux user and your app linux user are different. So, for security reason, you can't get private app data from adb, but you can make a copy as you did. I agree, it's messy and unclean but it's been designed that way. So my suggestion is to add [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) to your app. You can monitor your DB from Chrome, as well as getting other debug infos.

Answer (score 12):

this is easy to do:

1. plug in your device, and run `adb shell` from command line or terminal
2. Once in the shell `run-as com.myapplication.packagname`
3. then cd into the databases folder `cd databases`
4. Then run `cat my_datbase_name.db > /sdcard/my_database_name_temp.db`
5. run `exit` and then `exit` again to get back to the normal terminal prompt
6. run `adb pull /sdcard/my_database_name_temp.db` and that should be it

You can donwload [sqlitebrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to view this data

Comment: oh yes, this copies the file from the command prompt. Thanks.

Comment: @endlessProgrammer glad to help

Answer (score -1):

1. Run the app using android emulator then goto->tools->android device monitor
   dialog will opened go to File Explorer ->data folder
   (give permission to data folder)

   - open cmd using start menu
   - go to sdk folder (e.g., C:\Users\android-sdks\platform-tools>)
   - type adb shell
   - su
   - chmod 777 /data
   - chmod 777 /data/data/in.co.gesardisplays.www.rwfiles/files/gesar.txt
     changes will be affected in adb monitor
2. Pull the files to folder

   - exit from the shell
   - follow previous step 1.2
   - type adb root
   - adb pull /data/data/in.co.gesardisplays.www.rwfiles/files/
       **or** 
     select ur file click a pull a file icon it will be at top right of file explorer